# Display 2 cells of same class in a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a view in which i have several UITableViewCell.
2 of those UITableViewCell are from same class : S6OfferDetailsDescCell (same xib, same VC), let's call them cellA and cellB.
They are both supposed to content different text.
Sometimes it's working, but most of the time cellB contains the cellA text, not it's own text.
cellA is always working fine, always containing it's own text.

When both are containing their own text (so everything works well) i get this msg :

```
2015-09-01 15:57:58.166 visa 2[6589:165914] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

...

(

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c873800 V:[UIView:0x7ca6c6d0(408)]>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c88dc70 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7ca6c6d0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ca6c600 )>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c889340 V:[UIView:0x7ca6c6d0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ca6c600 )>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a77d970 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ca6c600(398)]>"

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 

<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c873800 V:[UIView:0x7ca6c6d0(408)]>
```

Any idea? is that possible to have 2 cells of same type (same xib) on a screen? Or should i create another xib (which will be an exact copy...)?
Thx

Edit :

I'm adding my 2 cells in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" like this :

```
...
//cellA
} else if (itemType == S6CellTypeOfferDetailsDescription) {

    S6OfferDetailsDescCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:S6OfferDetailsDescCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell loadWebViewWithHtmlString:_descriptionHtmlCode];
return cell;

}

...
//cellB
} else if (itemType == S6CellTypeOfferDetailsCGU) {

    S6OfferDetailsDescCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:S6OfferDetailsDescCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.descLbl.attributedText = _attrCGU;

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: The log you're showing is not related with your issue. The log is just about some constraint you haven't defined properly and it's trying to satisfy both but it's not possible. Regarding to your issue, you should provide some code of your `UITableViewController` to have an idea of what's wrong

Comment: Can you provide more details? How are the cells setup? Using IB or Code?

Comment: I've edited my msg, is that enough?

Comment: Oooohh i found the problem... that's stupid, i have a label and a webView in this cell, and i was using "load webView" method for cellA (which hides label), and using the label for cellB, so i just couldn't see the text which actually were in the label, just because it was previously hidden... Thx anyway :)